# How to make IE to install updated CAB File

Tags: asp.net, activex, cab

HI

My web page is hoting an ActiveX Contol packed in a CAB File.
IE is automatically installing the CAB file, if the ActiveX is not present on the client machine.

waht are steps i need to make sure.

So that the client should always have the updated ActiveX control,  if the web application has a new version of the activex control.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build new ActiveX control with **increased** version number. If previous was 1,0,0,0, the next could be 1,1,0,0, for example.

Modify inf file with **new version number**

```
[Foo.ocx]
  file-win32-x86=thiscab
  clsid={F00F00F0-0F00-F00F-00F0-0F00F00F00F0}
  FileVersion=1,1,0,0
```

Repack CAB file and place it to your server.

Update version number in your page:

```
<object id="foo" style="DISPLAY: none" codebase="foo.cab#version=1,1,0,0"
        height="10" width="10"
        classid="CLSID:F00F00F0-0F00-F00F-00F0-0F00F00F00F0">
</object>
```

Comment: HI Eugene, Here i have not created any OCX file. it is just a noramal setup file and i have packed this setup and inf file in a cab setup using cabarc.exe tool

and my Inf file is


[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
AdvancedINF=2.0
[Setup Hooks]
hook1=hook1

[hook1]
run=msiexec.exe /i "%EXTRACT_DIR%\PrintRenderer.msi" /qn